# Undefined method error when using ClojureScript and Domina

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I recently started trying out ClojureScript in a project. The following code:

```
(ns shrine.snippets
  (:use [domina.css :only [sel]]
        [domina.events :only [listen! target]]
        [domina :only [log]]))

(defn ^:export init []
  (listen! (sel "a.delete") :click
           (fn [evt]
             (log (target evt)))))
```

will trigger the following error when the "a.delete" link is clicked, when compiled with "advanced" optimisation.

```
Uncaught Error: No protocol method Event.target defined for type object: [object Object]
```

But there is no problem when compiled with "simple" optimisation.

Could someone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess you need to provide type hinting for evt, but I'm not 100% sure. Try asking on IRC?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error, but was unable; here is a ClojureScript project I made that contains code identical to yours but seems to work. https://github.com/levand/testproj

Comment: @levand Thanks for taking a look. I tried your example and it works. I will try to reproduce the problem with a minimal project.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with colliding namespaces that is described here https://github.com/levand/domina/issues/57